# Selenium Builder tests with Jenkins and Github

Tags: json, git, selenium, jenkins

My goal: setup a simple test framework using Selenium Builder as a FF plugin, GitHub and Jenkins. Retain the test files in .json format. I don't wish to go near java or maven for now.

My current setup: - Selenium Builder add-on for FF28 with Github plugin - Jenkins 1.567 with SeleniumBuilder plugin - Jenkins job setup as a freestyle project, building when a push is made to Git repo and 'Invoke selenium Builder script' as a build step with 'Script file' pointing to root of my test folder(.json scripts)

I can run my .json scripts using se-interpreter from command line using java -jar SeInterpreter.jar example_test.json

What I need to know is - how do I configure Jenkins and the se-interpreter-config file so I can run from Jenkins? currently my interpeter config file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "interpreter-config",
  "configurations": [
{
  "settings": [
{
  "driverOptions": {
    "host": localhost,
    "port": 4444

  },
  "browserOptions": {
    "browserName": "firefox",
  }
}
  ],
  "scripts": [

    "mySeleniumBuilderTests/tests/*"

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did. 
1. Add the Selenium Builder plugin to your Jenkins. 
2. Upload your test script (html or json) to git repo.
3. In Build, select Invoke Selenium Builder Script.
4. Put your script file name there.
5. Build with the URL of your git repo.
Done.